# Installing a PHP vulnerability scanner called RIPS

Tags: php, web-services, security

I am trying to run RIPS on my local webserver but I am not succeeding. RIPS website:  http://rips-scanner.sourceforge.net/  says to place the file into the /var/www.. I am new to setting up web servers but I feel like I am missing something rudimentary and I can not grasp my mind around it. So any tips on how to actually start RIPS please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

see [Readme.md](https://github.com/ripsscanner/rips/blob/master/README.md)

## Requirements

- web server: Apache or Nginx recommended
- PHP: latest version recommended
- browser: Firefox recommended

## Installation

- Download the latest release
- Extract the files to your local web server's document root
- Make sure your web server has file permissions
- Make sure your installation is protected from unauthorized access
- Open your browser at http://localhost/rips-xx/

Basically, set up a webserver with php, download rips and extract it into a subfolder of your `www-root` (`htdocs`, `/var/www/`, or whatever it is called in your linux distribution or webserver config), check that permissions are properly set and navigate your browser to that subdir on your webserver. You should see the rips welcome page. Once there, select a base folder (any absoulute path on the webserver), tick the "subdirs" checkbox, start the scan and wait for it to finish to triage the results.

For a quick and painless windows webserver setup you might want to download xampp and follow [this guide](https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_windows.html).
If you're on linux, use your package manager to install a webserver of your choice and a recent version of php (e.g. `yum ..` or `aptitude install apache2 php`)

If you feel like you want to run it in CLI mode see [my fork](https://github.com/tintinweb/rips-scanner) that adds optional cli support that allows you to run rips without having to install a webserver. Pretty handy if you have a build pipeline for continuous integration and automatically want to fail builds when rips detects defects in your codebase.